# How to change the return message of Exception.getMessage()?

Tags: java, exception

I need to change the return message of the method **getMessage()** ,
for instance, i have an **ArithmeticException**, and when i write:

```
try{c=a/0;}
catch(ArithmeticException excep){System.out.println( excep.getMessage() );}
```

and I execut this code I have: **/ by zero**.

So, I wanted to change this result by overwriting the **getMesage** method.
I  have created a **new class** called **MyException** that inherits from **ArithmeticExceprtion** and I override the methode **getMessage**, and after that I  have changed the type of the exception in my last code from **ArithmeticException** to my new name class **MyException**:

```
public class MyException extends ArithmeticException{
    @override
    public String getMessage(){
        retun "new code message";}
}
```

and I have changed the first code, I have wrotten:

```
try{c=a/0;}
catch(MyException excep){System.out.println( excep.getMessage() );}
```

and when I have executed this code, I had the same error's message as if I didn't catch the exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
         at main.test.main(Test.java:33)
```

So, my question is: how can I change the message of the methode **getMessage()** ?

Comment: this is an outright off-topic, totally ignoring what Programmers is **[about](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour)**: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a topic listed in the help center.

Comment: And where can I post this question plz ?

Comment: did you check [meta guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773) referred in prior comment?

Comment: Pls @Snowman what is SO ?, sorry I am a new here

Comment: @Amine 1. Click the link in gnat's comment. 2. I typed out "Stack Overflow" in my comment, then shortened it to "SO" later

Comment: Sorry @gnat, no i didn't check it yet

Answer (score 1):

`c=a/0` always throws a `ArithmeticException` because it's implemented this way.

If you write you're own division function that throws your `MyException` when dividing by 0 then you can actually catch it:

```
float division(float a, float b) {
    if(b == 0)
        throw new MyException();
    return a/b;
}

...
try {
    c = division(a, b);
} catch(MyException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: But we have to add     throws Myexception    in front of the function division, because we have throw, isn't it ?

Comment: you can either add `throws MyException` in the function declaration `myFunction(...) throws MyException` or catch it as shown above in the `try-catch` section

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your own defined exception, you have to throw it manually like

```
throw new MyException();
```

otherwise it will throw the instance of the class ArithmeticException, so its own getMessage() function will be triggered.